# How to resolve error #95313 when building a gatsby site?

Tags: build, gatsby

I have finished working on my gatsby project, but I have problem when trying to build. I got this #95313 error. I do not have any errors in project.

```
 ERROR 

Page data from page-data.json for the failed page "/success/": {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-success-index-tsx",
  "path": "/success/",
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {}
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": []
}

failed Building static HTML for pages - 1.268s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/success/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of null

  - useSelector.js:126 
    [my-gatsby-site]/[react-redux]/es/hooks/useSelector.js:126:1

  - index.tsx:13
    webpack:/my-gatsby-site/src/pages/success/index.tsx:13:42

  - static-entry.js:286
    webpack:/my-gatsby-site/.cache/static-entry.js:286:22

  - stylis.esm.js:74
    [my-gatsby-site]/[@emotion]/stylis/dist/stylis.esm.js:74:1
```

How can I resolve it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks you haven't finished the work (yet). If the project is not the building is because you have some underneath errors. If it works in `gatsby develop` it's only working under certain conditions. Can you provide some details about the implementation? Where are you using the store? How? What have you tried? What versions and OS are you running? How `/success/` looks like? What configuration do you have?

Comment: It looks finished in my opinion. No errors, no warnings, everything works as I expected. 
Here is my project repo https://github.com/Dovtutis/playEverywhere

Comment: Well, this is definitely an error: `failed Building static HTML for pages`. Your site worked under `gatsby develop` and not under `gatsby build` so, there's not finished yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are using [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement) wrapper in your `gatsby-browser.js` while you need also to use it in the `gatsby-ssr.js` because it's a shared API.

> Note: There is an equivalent hook in Gatsby’s SSR API. It is
> recommended to use both APIs together. For example usage, check out
> Using redux.

I've made a PR that should fix it: https://github.com/Dovtutis/playEverywhere/compare/main...fbuireu:patch-1

Comment: Your link goes to a 404 - would really like to read that page as I'm having a similar error!

Comment: Update: I followed your advice and wrapped the root element in gatsby-ssr.js and it worked! :)